# Magento Crossell also include out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, out-of-stock, cross-sells

**I want to include out of stock products, to my cross sell list.**
Currently only products in stock are displayed.

How can I change this, so that out of stock products are included?

Answer (score 0):

OK so your solution would be here.

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php`

Paste `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php`

and goto  `_getCollection()` method

and **comment** below line

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```